# Resolve warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from struct to struct

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, struct

I have the similar strcture in my application.

```
 typedef struct _Test
    {
        int n;
        struct Test *Next;
    }Test;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Test tmp, tmp1;

    tmp.n = 1;
    tmp.Next = NULL;

    tmp1.n = 0;
    tmp1.Next = &tmp;

    return 0;
}
```

at line

```
tmp1.Next = &tmp;
```

I am getting the following warning message:
warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'Test *' to 'Test *'

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: `struct Test *Next;` --> `struct _Test *Next;`

Comment: The real issue here is the warning ... it should really say *incompatible types from '`Test *`' to '`struct Test *`'*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typedef struct _Test
{
    int n;
    struct Test *Next; // --> struct Test is not a type here
}Test;
```

It should be

```
typedef struct _Test
{
    int n;
    struct _Test *Next; // --> struct _Test is a type
} Test;
```

So in order to define any object it should have a valid data type else you will end up with errors.

Comment: Why is it even possible to write `struct Test *Next;`?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Sorry what?

Comment: I mean that we have no struct named `Test` but `struct Test *Next;` seems to be valid construction...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: See my answer. Basically, `struct Test` is an incomplete type, and it is legal to have a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: Yep, I've checked it. Thanks for clarification. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

When you have:

```
typedef struct _Test
{
    int n;
    struct Test *Next;
} Test;
```

The `_Test` name exists in the *tag namespace*. You can declare a struct of that type using `struct _Test`. Inside your struct definition you use `struct Test`. Since a struct by this name hasn't been declared, it is considered an incomplete type. It is legal to have a pointer to an incomplete struct type, but it is illegal to dereference it until it has been fully declared.

You should avoid using names that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, as these identifiers are reserved. You should use:

```
struct Test
{
    int n;
    struct Test *next;
};
```

Or, if you don't want to type `struct Test` and want to type just `Test` everywhere, you can follow the above with:

```
typedef struct Test Test;
```

This, for lack of better words, copies the `Test` name out of the *tag namespace* so it can be used without the preceding `struct` keyword.